# Know Group name by Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How do I know the exact name of the Groups in my VSTS workItems using Rest APIs. 
I know the field names however As I do not know the group name or how to access the group. I am unable to add the field to the group

Comment: What do you mean by "group"?

Comment: Group to set in the following Rest API    ----           POST https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/_apis/work/processdefinitions/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/layout/groups/{groupId}/controls?api-version=4.1-preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the group name(s), you can use the REST API to [**get process definition's Layout**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/processdefinitions/layout/get):

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/_apis/work/processdefinitions/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/layout?api-version=4.1-preview
```

Such as

```
GET  https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/_apis/work/processdefinitions/c3c605d0-4ea8-492a-9d26-46612ccb51b1/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug/layout?api-version=4.1-preview
```

The response will look like:

```
{
    "pages": [
        {
            "id": "Scrum.Bug.Bug",
            "inherited": true,
            "label": "Details",
            "pageType": "custom",
            "locked": false,
            "visible": true,
            "isContribution": false,
            "sections": [
                {
                    "id": "Section1",
                    "groups": [

                        ... 

                        {
                            "id": "2fe29062-685e-4e36-89ba-6415becaebd7",
                            "label": "Group1",
                            "isContribution": false,
                            "visible": true,
                            "controls": [
                                {
                                    "id": "8c6bc312-cd08-44a7-a403-5bcbbe9baff1",
                                    "label": "control",
                                    "readOnly": false,
                                    "visible": true,
                                    "contribution": {
                                        "contributionId": "ms-devlabs.vsts-extensions-multivalue-control.multivalue-form-control",
                                        "inputs": {
                                            "FieldName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity",
                                            "Values": "control value"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "isContribution": true
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
...
}
```

And you can get the group name from label parameter under `sections` and `groups` objects.